# Is it possible to drag & drop textbox,text in a form using mvc. net c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've searched for this over the internet but couldn't find my answer..I want to add text box,textarea in a form and want to use this by dragging & dropping. I found this type of tutorial in asp.net mvc form but I want to use this in mvc. Is it possible to make this dynamic drag & drop in asp. Net mvc?

Answer (score 0):

I think this idea is not correct in terms of `MVC` approach.

**Considering the question why not use drag and drop in MVC ?**

The `MVC` approach is not `event-driven` development such as `ASP.NET WebForms`

`MVC` has no server controls so not like manipulate components **directly on events** .

`MVC` instead HTML controls and HTML helpers used and components are managed through actions